# Return Unique set with "DISTINCT" and multiple other Selected columns

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am creating a view from multiple tables. Each table being included has a column named Contact_ID. I am using MS SQL 2005. I see that I can use DISTINCT to return a unique set by Contact_ID but then my view only shows the Contact_ID.

I need the view to contain more than just the Contact_ID so I need to create a SELECT statement with all the correct columns but I can't have duplicate records.

Here is what I currently have: (This returns all the data I need but contains records with duplicates of Contact_ID)

```
SELECT dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Date_entered_into_Database, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Date_of_Initial_Contact, 
         dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].[Company_ Name], dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Contact_Title, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Contact_First_Name, 
         dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Contact_Middle, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Contact_Last_Name, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Credential, 
         dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Contact_Occupation, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Degree_1, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Degree_2, 
         dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Degree_3, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Date_of_Highest_Degree, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Work_Setting, 
         dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Website_Address, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Email_1_Key_Contact, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Email_2, 
         dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Email_3, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Day_Time_Phone_Number, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Extension, 
         dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Mobile_Phone_Number, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Bus_Fax_Number, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Home_Phone_Number, 
         dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Home_Fax_Number, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Mailing_Street_1, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Mailing_Street_2, 
         dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Mailing_City, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Mailing_State, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].[Mailing_Zip/Postal], 
         dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Mailing_Country, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].[Bad_Address?], dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].[PROV/REG?], 
         dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].status_flag, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].status_flag AS status_flag2, dbo.Providers.Contact_ID AS Expr1, 
         dbo.Providers.Referral_Source, dbo.Resource_Center.access, dbo.Referral.Contact_Source, dbo.Resource_Center.cert_start_date, 
         dbo.Resource_Center.cert_exp_date, dbo.prov_training_records.Contact_ID AS Expr2, dbo.prov_training_records.date_reg_email_sent
FROM   dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts] INNER JOIN
         dbo.Referral ON dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Referral.Referral_ID INNER JOIN
         dbo.prov_training_records ON dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.prov_training_records.Contact_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.Resource_Center ON dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Resource_Center.Contact_ID FULL OUTER JOIN
         dbo.Providers ON dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Providers.Contact_ID
```

Same query with table names aliased:

```
SELECT c.Contact_ID, c.Date_entered_into_Database, c.Date_of_Initial_Contact, 
       c.[Company_ Name], c.Key_Contact_Title, c.Key_Contact_First_Name, 
       c.Key_Contact_Middle, c.Key_Contact_Last_Name, c.Key_Credential, 
       c.Key_Contact_Occupation, c.Key_Degree_1, c.Key_Degree_2, 
       c.Key_Degree_3, c.Date_of_Highest_Degree, c.Work_Setting, 
       c.Website_Address, c.Email_1_Key_Contact, c.Email_2, 
       c.Email_3, c.Day_Time_Phone_Number, c.Extension, 
       c.Mobile_Phone_Number, c.Bus_Fax_Number, c.Home_Phone_Number, 
       c.Home_Fax_Number, c.Mailing_Street_1, c.Mailing_Street_2, 
       c.Mailing_City, c.Mailing_State, c.[Mailing_Zip/Postal], 
       c.Mailing_Country, c.[Bad_Address?], c.[PROV/REG?], 
       c.status_flag, c.status_flag AS status_flag2, p.Contact_ID AS Expr1, 
       p.Referral_Source, rc.access, r.Contact_Source, rc.cert_start_date, 
       rc.cert_exp_date, tr.Contact_ID AS Expr2, tr.date_reg_email_sent
FROM   dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts] c INNER JOIN
       dbo.Referral r ON c.Contact_ID = r.Referral_ID INNER JOIN
       dbo.prov_training_records tr ON c.Contact_ID = tr.Contact_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.Resource_Center rc ON c.Contact_ID = rc.Contact_ID FULL OUTER JOIN
       dbo.Providers p ON c.Contact_ID = p.Contact_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID ORDER BY dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID) AS rn
        FROM    dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts]
        INNER JOIN
                dbo.Referral
        ON      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Referral.Referral_ID
        INNER JOIN
                dbo.prov_training_records
        ON      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.prov_training_records.Contact_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Resource_Center
        ON      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Resource_Center.Contact_ID
        FULL OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Providers
        ON      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Providers.Contact_ID
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: I get the error: "The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported."

Comment: @Dale: what does this query return: `select compatibility_level from  sys.databases where name = db_name()`?

Comment: Also, see the comment thread under SQLMenace's answer about using MAX (however, that's not a requirement for this question. I was planning on making a new question for that part of it)

Comment: @Dale: are you using `Management Studio` to run the query?

Comment: @Dale: could you please post the exact error message: `Msg *, Level *` etc.?

Comment: @Quassnoi, I just get a pop up window with the following info: Window Title - "Query Definitions Differ", Description - "The following errors were encountered while parsing the contents of the SQL pane:", Error - "The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported.", "The query cannot be represented graphically in the Diagram and Criteria Pane." However, I do not have the Diagram or Criteria panes open.

Comment: Well, since OVER doesn't work, is there an older work-around that can be done in place of OVER? That way I can use the code you supplied.

Comment: @Dale - `Over` *does* work in SQL Server 2005. There is something else amiss here.

Comment: Was able to create the view with the query you provided now thanks to the solution over here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784072/no-support-for-over-in-ms-sql-server-2005). Weird thing is that it actually returns more records now, I would expect the opposite as this was supposed to de-duplicate the records...

Answer (score 1):

Initially misread the question, you will need to group all the data but if you want to show all the data and there are uniques, you need to use min or max in some cases, if someone has 2 phones...what do you want to show?

Comment: Precisely, if a record has a value in column "Contact_Source", I would like to use that record over one that is NULL.

Comment: in that case use GROUP by and MAX

Comment: Hmm, can't seem to get this right. How would I use GROUP BY and MAX in my example?