# No Support for OVER in MS SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

OVERI am getting an error when trying to run a query in MS SQL Server Management Studio. We use MS SQL Server 2005 on a windows 2003 server.

Here is the query:

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID ORDER BY dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID) AS rn
        FROM    dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts]
        INNER JOIN
                dbo.Referral
        ON      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Referral.Referral_ID
        INNER JOIN
                dbo.prov_training_records
        ON      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.prov_training_records.Contact_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Resource_Center
        ON      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Resource_Center.Contact_ID
        FULL OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Providers
        ON      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Providers.Contact_ID
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
```

When I run it I just get a pop up window with the following info:

Window Title - "Query Definitions Differ"

Description - "The following errors were encountered while parsing the contents of the SQL pane:"

Error - "The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported."

Then at the end it says - "The query cannot be represented graphically in the Diagram and Criteria Pane."

However, I do not have the Diagram or Criteria panes open.

I need to make sure we have the correct syntax. If the syntax is correct then I either need to fix why the Management Studio throws this error or find a work-around to OVER and solve this with a different approach.

I know that the specs say "OVER" is supported, nevertheless I get the error.

In a new query window if I run this it works:

```
USE abtcontacts;
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Date_entered_into_Database, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Date_of_Initial_Contact, 
                      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].[Company_ Name], dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Contact_Title, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Contact_First_Name, 
                      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Contact_Middle, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Contact_Last_Name, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Credential, 
                      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Contact_Occupation, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Degree_1, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Degree_2, 
                      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Key_Degree_3, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Date_of_Highest_Degree, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Work_Setting, 
                      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Website_Address, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Email_1_Key_Contact, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Email_2, 
                      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Email_3, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Day_Time_Phone_Number, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Extension, 
                      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Mobile_Phone_Number, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Bus_Fax_Number, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Home_Phone_Number, 
                      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Home_Fax_Number, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Mailing_Street_1, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Mailing_Street_2, 
                      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Mailing_City, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Mailing_State, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].[Mailing_Zip/Postal], 
                      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Mailing_Country, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].[Bad_Address?], dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].[PROV/REG?], 
                      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].status_flag, dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].status_flag AS status_flag2, dbo.Providers.Referral_Source, dbo.Referral.Contact_Source, 
                      dbo.Resource_Center.cert_start_date, dbo.Resource_Center.cert_exp_date, dbo.prov_training_records.Contact_ID AS Expr2, 
                      dbo.prov_training_records.date_reg_email_sent, dbo.Resource_Center.access, dbo.Providers.Contact_ID AS Expr1,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID ORDER BY dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID) AS rn
        FROM    dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts]
        INNER JOIN
                dbo.Referral
        ON      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Referral.Referral_ID
        INNER JOIN
                dbo.prov_training_records
        ON      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.prov_training_records.Contact_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Resource_Center
        ON      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Resource_Center.Contact_ID
        FULL OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Providers
        ON      dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Providers.Contact_ID
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Solving this problem will help me solve my other problem [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780176/return-unique-set-with-distinct-and-multiple-other-selected-columns)

Comment: What if you press `CTRL+N` and run it in a blank script window? I very much doubt the visual designers could cope with that query.

Comment: If you click the "New Query" button and enter your query in the window it makes, does it work?

Comment: `[1_MAIN - Contacts] is a horrible table name.

Comment: @Martin - When I run the query in a new window I get: "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.1_MAIN - Contacts'."

Comment: It will be running in your default database. Add `USE YourDatabaseName;` to the beginning of the script (or just select your database from the listbox)

Comment: @Hogan - Tell me about it. I just took over here and everything is a mess.

Comment: @Dale - Are you positive you are firing this against the right database?

Comment: @Martin - If I run it with "USE abtcontacts;" at the beginning, I get this error: "Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 2. The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 'q'."

Comment: @Dale - Replace the `*` with the actual columns you want. The column names must be unique.

Comment: @Martin - K, that works. However, I need to save that as a view so I can select from the view with asp.net on our website. I just edited my question with the SQL I am running in the new query window (which works in a new query window).

Comment: @Dale - just use `CREATE VIEW dbo.Foo AS WITH q AS ... ` followed by the rest of the query (or use `ALTER  VIEW dbo.Foo AS WITH q AS ... ` if this is to replace an already existing view)

Comment: @Martin - That seems to have worked. Could you post an answer so I can reward you?

Comment: @Dale - You might as well tick Thomas's as his answer has all the info in except for that last step!

Comment: @Martin - K, will do, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried prepending a semicolon in front of your `With` statement? (e.g. `;With q As`)

---

Some general notes:

1. You must run this in a query not the designer. It sounds like you have fixed that.
2. Enumerate the columns instead of using `*`. I.e., in the example below replace Col1, Col2 with the actual columns you want prefixed by the table from whence they came.
3. Put `use DatabaseName` at the top of your script followed by a line break, followed by `GO`, followed by another line-break.
4. If the only statement prior to the `With` statement is the `GO` between your `use` statement and the query, then no semicolon is necessary since it is the first statement in the batch.

```
use DatabaseName
GO
WITH q AS
        (
        SELECT  TableName.Col1, TableName.Col2,...
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID 
                                                        ORDER BY dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID ) AS rn
        FROM dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts]
            INNER JOIN dbo.Referral
                ON dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Referral.Referral_ID
            INNER JOIN dbo.prov_training_records
                ON dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.prov_training_records.Contact_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Resource_Center
                ON dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Resource_Center.Contact_ID
            FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Providers
                ON dbo.[1_MAIN - Contacts].Contact_ID = dbo.Providers.Contact_ID
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
```

Comment: I've never used a semicolon in T-SQL. It's hard to imagine how it would help.

Comment: @Gabe - To use common-table expressions, the query must either be the first statement in the batch or the previous statement must be closed via a semicolon. "Technically", you are supposed to end every statement with a semicolon but you are not required (yet).

Comment: @Dale - I've expanded my answer to cover the various issues so far. If the only thing prior to `With` is a `GO` command, then you do not need the semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using the Query Designer GUI. Stop doing that. The Query Designer is rubbish. It's useless for any non-trivial query development. Type you queries in a Management Studio editor window.

Comment: Sweet, I would love to, I actually don't use the GUI features, I just use it to run queries and create new "views". This SQL is to create a "view" which I can later select from.

Comment: @Dale, right. So don't use the view designer. The way to create a view is with a CREATE VIEW statement. If you do that then you won't get the error that you have been experiencing. The error is purely a GUI bug/feature.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=SQL.90).aspx) says that `OVER` is certainly supported.

The problem is that the editor window doesn't support it. See if you can close all the panes other than SQL and results view to make the error go away.

Comment: Yeah, I remove all the other panes but it still happens unless I run it in a new query window.

Answer (score 1):

Check the compatibility level on the particular database

There is some more detail @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178653(v=SQL.90).aspx

If the compatibility level is less than 90, then new features, like the OVER clause, available only in SQL 2005, are turned off.

Comment: This is not the OP's issue (I think). They are in the script editor you get to via clicking "edit table". I just tried `select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by number) FROM master..spt_values` and it definitely didn't like that.

Comment: I just realised that someone questioned the compatibility level in the comments in OPs other question ... the answer was 90, so definitely not the case