# SQL Server Pagination w/o row_number() or nested subqueries?

Tags: sql-server, pagination, limit, row-number

I have been fighting with this all weekend and am out of ideas. In order to have pages in my search results on my website, I need to return a subset of rows from a SQL Server 2005 Express database (i.e. start at row 20 and give me the next 20 records). In MySQL you would use the "LIMIT" keyword to choose which row to start at and how many rows to return.

In SQL Server I found ROW_NUMBER()/OVER, but when I try to use it it says "Over not supported". I am thinking this is because I am using SQL Server 2005 Express (free version). Can anyone verify if this is true or if there is some other reason an OVER clause would not be supported?

Then I found the old school version similar to:

`SELECT TOP X * FROM TABLE WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP Y ID FROM TABLE ORDER BY ID) ORDER BY ID` where X=number per page and Y=which record to start on.

However, my queries are a lot more complex with many outer joins and sometimes ordering by something other than what is in the main table. For example, if someone chooses to order by how many videos a user has posted, the query might need to look like this:

```
SELECT TOP 50 iUserID, iVideoCount FROM MyTable LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT count(iVideoID) AS iVideoCount, iUserID FROM VideoTable GROUP BY iUserID) as TempVidTable ON MyTable.iUserID = TempVidTable.iUserID WHERE iUserID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 100 iUserID, iVideoCount FROM MyTable LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT count(iVideoID) AS iVideoCount, iUserID FROM VideoTable GROUP BY iUserID) as TempVidTable ON MyTable.iUserID = TempVidTable.iUserID ORDER BY iVideoCount) ORDER BY iVideoCount
```

The issue is in the **subquery** SELECT line: TOP 100 iUserID, iVideoCount

To use the "NOT IN" clause it seems I can only have 1 column in the subquery ("SELECT TOP 100 iUserID FROM ..."). But when I don't include iVideoCount in that subquery SELECT statement then the ORDER BY iVideoCount in the subquery doesn't order correctly so my subquery is ordered differently than my parent query, making this whole thing useless. There are about 5 more tables linked in with outer joins that can play a part in the ordering.

I am at a loss! The two above methods are the only two ways I can find to get SQL Server to return a subset of rows. I am about ready to return the whole result and loop through each record in PHP but only display the ones I want. That is such an inefficient way to things it is really my last resort.

Any ideas on how I can make SQL Server mimic MySQL's LIMIT clause in the above scenario?

Comment: `row_number() over()` is supported in SQL Server 2005. There must be something else that gives the error. Can you show a query using `row_number` that does not work for you?

Comment: look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784072/no-support-for-over-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, although [SQL Server 2005 Row_Number()](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-paging-row_number-sql-server-function.aspx) can be used for paging and with [SQL Server 2012 data paging](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/sql-paging-in-sql-server-2012-sql-order-by-offset-fetch-next-rows.aspx) support is enhanced with Order By Offset and Fetch Next, in case you can not use any of these solutions you require to first

1. create a temp table with identity column.
2. then insert data into temp table with ORDER BY clause
3. Use the temp table Identity column value just like the ROW_NUMBER() value

I hope it helps,