# Single query to return multiple rows as columns based on initial column

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have a table, employee history with the following

```
ID | Current_Dept | Dept_Start_Date | Name
1 | Sales | 2012-01-01 | John Smith
1 | Marketing | 2010-01-01 | John Smith
1 | Intern | 2008-01-01 | John Smith
2 | IT | 2012-01-01 | Sue Jones
2 | Sales | 2011-01-01 | Sue Jones
2 | eBusiness | 2010-10-01 | Sue Jones
3 | Warehouse | 2012-01-01 | Bobby Ray
3 | Sales | 2009-01-01 | Bobby Ray
```

What I would like is a query giving everyone who ever worked in Sales:

```
ID | DeptBefore | DeptAfter | CurrentDept
1  | Marketing  |           | Sales
2  | ebusiness  | IT        | IT
3  |            | Warehouse | Warehouse
```

At the moment I see no simpler way of doing this other then recursively querying the table for each row.

I'm tempted to create a 'temp' table that's populated once a day and run the query off of that.

I'm using SQL Server and C# (ASP.NET) incase these offer other simpler solutions.

I hope that all makes sense.

Thanks,

Comment: are you trying to retrieve the list of employees that have ever worked in the sales department?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your data it *appears* that you want the departments `immediately` before and after the sales department.  For example; you don't show that John Smith started as an intern.

*NOTE: You may want to consider the results you want if someone has worked for sales on two different occasions.*

```
WITH
  sequenced AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dept_start_date DESC) AS sequence_id
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  salesRecord.id,
  prevRecord.current_dept     AS DeptBefore,
  nextRecord.current_dept     AS DeptAfter,
  lastRecord.current_dept     AS DeptCurrent
FROM
  sequenced     AS salesRecord
LEFT JOIN
  sequenced     AS prevRecord
    ON  prevRecord.id          = salesRecord.id
    AND prevRecord.sequence_id = salesRecord.sequence_id - 1
LEFT JOIN
  sequenced     AS nextRecord
    ON  nextRecord.id          = salesRecord.id
    AND nextRecord.sequence_id = salesRecord.sequence_id + 1
LEFT JOIN
  sequenced     AS lastRecord
    ON  lastRecord.id          = salesRecord.id
    AND lastRecord.sequence_id = 1
WHERE
  salesRecord.CurrentDept = 'Sales'
```

By ordering the items in Descending order, the *current* record is always `sequence_id = 1`.

Comment: Used this works great! Never heard of OVER before, had an issue with it in the Visual Studio GUI. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784072/no-support-for-over-in-ms-sql-server-2005 told me to use Server management Studio and simply type the query.

Answer (score 1):

Use CTE can help you.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    current_dept NVARCHAR(100),
    Dept_Start_Date DATETIME,
    Name NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Temp
(ID, current_dept, Dept_Start_Date, Name)
VALUES
(1, 'Sales', '2012-01-01', 'John Smith'), 
(1, 'Marketing', '2010-01-01', 'John Smith'), 
(1, 'Intern', '2008-01-01', 'John Smith'),
(2, 'IT', '2012-01-01', 'Sue Jones'), 
(2, 'Sales', '2011-01-01', 'Sue Jones'), 
(2, 'eBusiness', '2010-01-01', 'Sue Jones'),
(3, 'Warehouse', '2012-01-01', 'Bobby Ray'),
(3, 'Sales', '2009-01-01', 'Bobby Ray')

DECLARE @current_dept NVARCHAR(100) = 'Sales'
;WITH CurrentDeptCTE AS 
(
    SELECT ID, current_dept, Dept_Start_Date, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Dept_Start_Date DESC) AS SEQUENCE
    FROM @Temp
)
SELECT SalesDept.ID, DeptBefore.current_dept AS 'DeptBefore', DeptAfter.current_dept     AS 'DeptAfter', CurrentDept.current_dept AS 'CurrentDept'
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, SEQUENCE
    FROM CurrentDeptCTE
    WHERE current_dept = @current_dept
) SalesDept
LEFT JOIN CurrentDeptCTE AS DeptBefore ON SalesDept.ID = DeptBefore.ID AND            SalesDept.SEQUENCE = DeptBefore.SEQUENCE - 1
LEFT JOIN CurrentDeptCTE AS DeptAfter ON SalesDept.ID = DeptAfter.ID AND SalesDept.SEQUENCE = DeptAfter.SEQUENCE + 1
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT ID, current_dept
    FROM CurrentDeptCTE 
    WHERE SEQUENCE = 1
) CurrentDept ON SalesDept.ID = CurrentDept.ID
```