# SQL Server Query Create List not just TOP

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which I can only get working for the top record, however now I have to change it so it will produce a list of games to be dispatched.

At the moment it is based on `User_ID = 1` but I need to be run for all `user_ID`.

Anyone any idea how I could change this query?

This Query Should Produce a list of Users who are due a game along with the game they are due.

1. List the users that have not reached their game quota for that month based on the subscription package they have chosen and rental table
2. Compare this list of users to their favourites list and asign a game to them based on what game is their highest priority and by date.
3. The game or games selected must be in stock which needs compared to quantity levels in games table.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48bc1/1
 [image]

The expected result from this sql Fiddle is:-

```
Leona Hill Blur XBOX 360
Rodney Hill Blur XBOX 360
Gillian Hill Formal 1 PS3
Gillian Hill Need for Speed XBOX 360
```

Comment: . . It would help if you edited your question and added sample data and the desired results.

Comment: Good God this is some script, Could you please narrow down your problem to 2 or 3 tables and what are the characteristics of this new list that you are after, I doubt it very much if any one will be willing to go through these 10-15 tables script to answer your question

Comment: Gordon you should see the sql fiddle there are like 15 tables with some sample data good luck with that pal :)

Comment: @M.Ali . . . I'm not going near it.  I have no reason to think that the current method is a reasonable way to solve the problem at hand, when the problem itself is not stated.

Comment: Sorry I will redo sql fiddle

Comment: You misunderstood, we just want to know what is the expected result even if we have to redo the entire query

Comment: @Ryx5 I have updated question with all detail you have asked and better sql fiddle with database image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the data in the SQLFiddle - I notice there is no 'LASTNAME' column there.

Also, I'm still digesting if this is correct or not but please give it a look.

```
/* Find the next games for a user to rent */
/* You cant do it in one swoop because each customers choice will affect the next one */
/* and you have to insert the result into the rentals in between. */

SELECT FIRSTNAME, GAME_NAME, GAME_PLATFORM
FROM [Games]
JOIN (SELECT [Favourites_ID], [User_ID], [Game_name], [Game_platform],
  [Priority], [Priority_level], [DatePicked],
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [User_ID] ORDER BY [Priority], [DatePicked]) AS Rank
 FROM Favourites) [Favourites]
  ON [Favourites].[Game_name] = [Games].[Name]
JOIN [Users]
  ON [Users].[User_ID] = [Favourites].[User_ID]
JOIN (SELECT [User_ID], MIN([RemainingRentable]) RemainingRentable FROM (
      /* Remaining rentable at a time */
      SELECT
        [Subscriptions].[Game_at_a_time] - (
          /* Number of games currently rented by the customer */
          SELECT COUNT(*) AS [CurraentlyRented]
          FROM [Rentals]
          WHERE [Rentals].[Date_returned] IS NULL
            AND [Users].[User_ID] = [Rentals].[User_ID]
        ) AS RemainingRentable,
      [Users].[User_ID]
      FROM [Users]
      JOIN [Subscriptions]
        ON [Users].[Subscription_ID] = [Subscriptions].[Subscription_ID]
      UNION
      /* Remaining rentable this month */
      SELECT
        [Subscriptions].[Max_games] - (
          /* Number of total games rented by the customer this month */
          SELECT COUNT(*) AS [RentedThisMonth]
          FROM [Rentals]
          WHERE MONTH([Rentals].[Date_rented]) = MONTH(GETDATE())
            AND YEAR([Rentals].[Date_rented]) = MONTH(GETDATE())
            AND [Users].[User_ID] = [Rentals].[User_ID]
        ) AS RemainingRentable,
      [Users].[User_ID]
      FROM [Users]
      JOIN [Subscriptions]
        ON [Users].[Subscription_ID] = [Subscriptions].[Subscription_ID] ) A
      GROUP BY [User_ID]
    ) Rentability 
  ON [Rentability].[User_ID] = [Users].[User_ID]
WHERE 
[Games].[Quantity] > (
    /* Number of currently rented copies */
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Rentals]
    WHERE [Games].[Game_barcode] = [Rentals].[Game_barcode]
      AND [Rentals].[Date_returned] IS NULL
  )
AND Rank <= RemainingRentable
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, GAME_NAME, GAME_PLATFORM
```

Comment: Thats 95% there Zak :) .. When I run it its giving me Gillian 3 games to be posted to here however looking at Rentals Table she already has one game and you can only have 2 games max at a time.  So the query is not taken into consideration the rentals table.  Would it be something like a count(*) rentals where date_returned IS NULL and IF county is less that assign game.  It might have to be the first part the query does.

Comment: I'm thinking we need a subquery that has an incrementing counter (rank) for each user - and only take the games where the rank =< RemainingRentable

Comment: Added Priority <= RemainingRentable as a filter... I'm assuming Priority gets updated frequently so its always a list starting at '1' per user...

Comment: Yep a user updates their game priority when they want, when they choose it initally it gets stores as priority 2 which is medium level, 1 is high and 3 is low.

Comment: I think the latest edit should solve the problem. I ranked each favorite game by priority level and time it was picked (earlier ranking higher)... Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks good Zak .. I just tried it there inside visual studio and it is saying The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported :(

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: 2010 Professional, oh no please tell me It will still work.  It works perfectly on SQL Fiddle exactly what I need.

Comment: I think its just your query window that doesn't support it. Do you have SQL Server Management Studio? The database itself should support this query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784072/no-support-for-over-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: Nope only have visual studio.  I am putting your query into a sqldatasource and when I execute it it gives me that error.

Comment: If you define this query as a view and then select from the view it should work.

Comment: Im sorry to be a pain, you already have helped me sooo much and I really apprecaite it but I have never use view or even heard tell of it to tell you the truth.  What are they?

Comment: Its ok figured it out, all working :D :D :D Thanks sooo much you have no idea how long I have been pulling my hair out with this query