# Show only records with most recent date

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which returns information about stock takes, the query works however as you can see in the image below there is some duplicates. I want it to display like in the image but instead of having duplicates i only want it to show the rows with the most recent date.

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT STOCK_CODE, TRANS_DATE, STOCK_QTY, DESCRIPTION, DETAIL
FROM         Tencia.dbo.STK_TRANS
WHERE     (TRANS_TYPE = N'STADJ') AND (STOCK_CODE LIKE 'LL%') AND (DESCRIPTION LIKE 'stock%') OR
                      (DESCRIPTION LIKE '%stk count%')
GROUP BY STOCK_CODE, TRANS_DATE, STOCK_QTY, DESCRIPTION, DETAIL
ORDER BY STOCK_CODE, TRANS_DATE DESC
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
        *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STOCK_CODE ORDER BY TRANS_DATE DESC)
    FROM Tencia.dbo.STK_TRANS
    WHERE
        (TRANS_TYPE = N'STADJ') 
        AND (STOCK_CODE LIKE 'LL%')
        AND (DESCRIPTION LIKE 'stock%')
        OR (DESCRIPTION LIKE '%stk count%')
)
SELECT
    STOCK_CODE,
    TRANS_DATE,
    STOCK_QTY,
    DESCRIPTION,
    DETAIL
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

---

Are you sure about your `WHERE` clause? Isn't it supposed to be like this:

```
WHERE
        TRANS_TYPE = N'STADJ'
        AND STOCK_CODE LIKE 'LL%'
        AND (
            DESCRIPTION LIKE 'stock%'
            OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%stk count%'
        )
```

Comment: That query does not work SQL Magement Studio throws error, i am trying to make a view by the way.

Comment: It says that the query cannot be represented graphically, i think it is because i am trying to make a view which will be displayed in an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: How are you creating the view? Are you using the Query Designer GUI? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5784249/2203084

Comment: Yeah i am, is that not the best way for this circumstance? I see, i read that post. I tried in standard query and it works as expected. Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Use a `CREATE VIEW` statement for this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx